# Gödel's Proof book - circular reasoning?

Tags: logic

Trying to make my way through the book *Gödel's Proof* (Nagel & Newman, edited by Hofstadter).

In chapter V, the authors are showing that the axioms of sentential calculus are not contradictory. In short, they say (or seem to say):

Let's assume that the calculus is contradictory, such that $S$ and its contradiction $\sim S$ are both true. Then the theorem  $p \supset ( \sim p \supset q )$ can be substituted with $S$ and $ \sim S$ to force $q$ to become true! Hence, if the calculus is contradictory, then any formula whatsoever is deducible from the axioms.

The way to show that the calculus is not contradictory is to find a formula that's not always true. In the text they use the example $p \vee q$. It's not always true, hence, it is shown that the calculus is consistent.

However... how can you assume that $p \vee q$ cannot be true? If the calculus is inconsistent, why couldn't there be a lengthy transformation that shows that $p \vee q$ is true?

It seems like a somewhat circular argument... what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: But p, q can be chosen to be both false. So we know that p or q is not always true.

Comment: True means truth-table "always true." That has no direct connection with provability from a specific set of axioms for propositional logic.

Comment: @almagest But if the calculus is contradictory, then you can prove that p or q is true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *truth* of a formula in propositional calculus is defined through the *semantics* for the language, based on *valuations*.

A formula of *propositional logic* is called a *tautology* when it is true for every valuation, like : $p \lor \lnot p$.

A simple way to check if a formula of propositional logic is a tautology or not is to use the truth-table method.

For *propositional logic*, we can prove two meta-theorems :

> *(i)* **Soundness** : if a formula $\varphi$ is provable in the propositional calculus, it is a *tautology* (i.e. if $\vdash \varphi$, then $\vDash \varphi$).
>
> *(ii)* A logical calculus is *consistent* iff there is at least one formula $\varphi$ not provable in it (i.e. $\nvdash \varphi$).

Now, we can cook them together in the following way : $p \lor q$ is not a *tautology*, because with the valuation $v$ such that $v(p)=v(q)=$**f** we have that $v(p \lor q)=$**f**. Thus, having found a valuation that does not satisfy it, we conclude that the formula is not true for all valuations, and thus it is not a *tautology*.

Thus, by *(i)* (soundness), it is not provable in the calculus.

Having found a formula not provable in the propositional calculus, we conclude by *(ii)* that the calculus is *consistent*.

Comment: As always, a very clear exposition!

Comment: Thanks, I agree it's clear that $p \vee $q is not a tautology. However, if we ignore the truth table analysis of $p \vee $q, how do we know there's not a way to transform $p \vee $q into a tautology, step by step?  For example, we might start with $p \vee q$, then go to $(p \land p) \lor (q \lor q)$. Then DeMorganize that to $\lnot(\lnot(p \land p) \land  \lnot(q \lor q))$.  Then continue like that for, say, 5000 steps... how do we know we will never arrive at some actual tautology, such as $p \lor \lnot p$?

Comment: @DerekRoss - $p \lor q$ is not a *tautology*, fullstop. But assuming that we can derive a tautology from it, so what ? In inconsistent calculus is a claculus taht prove absolutely everything : this does not mean that all formulae are tautology or that all formulae are true.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $v$ is the truth functional, correct? $v(\phi) = \text{true}$ if proposition/wff $\phi$ evaluates to true under some model, and $\text{false}$ otherwise?

Comment: @user525966 - $v$ is a truth valuation (an interpretation). If $v(\phi) = \text {true]$, then $v$ *satisfies* formula $\phi$.